# C++ Problem: [Error] statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function x2

Tags: c++

I'm a complete noob here in need of help. I'm hoping you guys, who are more experienced than me, can help me out.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Here is how the code is supposed to go since it's too long:

```
#include <iostream>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    class Payslip
    {
    
    string name, pay_grade;
    float salary, oth, otp, gross, net, tax, sss, pagibig, philhealth;
    
    public: 
    void payslipdetails()
    {
    
    // Extremely long, but this part of the code would allow me to allow user to input their names, their base salary, and overtime hours.
    
    sss = 500;
    pagibig = 200;
    philhealth = 100;
    otp = oth * (salary*0.01);
    gross = salary + otp;
    net = gross - (tax + sss + pagibig + philhealth);
    
    // then a series of if/else if condition if salary is greater/less than or equals to, and we divide the said salaries into pay grade A or B. 

/* Example: 
                if (salary >= 10000 && salary <= 19999)
                {
                    // Pay grade A
                    if (salary >= 10000 && salary <= 14999) 
                    {
                    pay_grade = "A";
                    }
                    
                        // Pay grade B
                        else if (salary >= 15000 && salary <= 19999)
                        {
                            pay_grade = "B";
                        }
                    tax = gross * 0.10;
                }*/
                
    
    }
    }
    
    void display_details()
    {
    cout<<"\n Employee Name              : " << name;
                    cout<<"\n Basic Salary               : " << salary;
                    cout<<"\n Pay Grade                  : " << pay_grade;
                    cout<<"\n No. of OT hours            : " << oth;
                    cout<<"\n OT Pay                     : " << otp;
                    cout<<"\n Gross Pay                  : " << gross;
                    cout<<"\n Withholding Tax            : " << tax;
                    cout<<"\n Net Pay                    : " << net;
            }
    };
    int main()
    {
            Payslip d;
            d.payslipdetails;
            d.display_details;
            return 0;
    }
```

There is an error in d.payslipdetails and d.displaydetails. I hope this is more clear than my last post!

The error is: [Error] statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function

I'm not sure how to do this...

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. What is `Payslip`?

Comment: if you dont tell us what is the error, we can't help you...

Comment: If you plan to call those two functions, you're missing the `()` parenthesis.

Comment: Without them, the expression can only be evaluated as a (discarded) pointer to function, but since those are overloaded the compiler cannot select a unique one. Hence the error message.

Comment: The definition of the `Payslip` will be greatly appreciated as well! ;)

Comment: It wasn't letting me post the whole thing... :( I'll send an image of the code if I can.

Comment: Never post code as image! Please visit the [Welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Don't post the whole thing. Just the `Payslip` class (and from that you can probably remove everything but data members, constructors, `payslipdetails` and `display_details`)

Comment: Reply to @YSC oh man, thank you so much. The parenthesis is what was really needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you possibly trying to call a method at the object `d`? Then you need at least add parentheses. as for each function call:

```cpp
    d.payslipdetails();
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the method name
paySlipDetails(); provide any requred parameters as per implementation code of Payslip class.